# Create a list from a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am looking for a different way to get a string list from a tuple of tuples. This is how I do right now:

```
x = (('a',1), (2,3), (4,), (), (None,))
op_list = []
for item in x:
    if item and item[0]:
        op_list.append(str(item[0]))
print op_list
```

Output: ['a', '2', '4']

I cannot think of any other way to get to the list. My question is, is there any better/alternate/pretty way of doing this?

EDIT: Added a few pitfall inputs to the input, like an empty tuple, tuple with None and given the expected output as well. Also edited the question to ensure that I need only a list of strings irrespective of any other data type other than None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> x = (('a',1), (2,3), (4,))
>>> [str(item[0]) for item in x if item and item[0]]
['a', '2', '4']
```

Comment: A one-liner without any temporary variable. Cool solution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) functions gives you the easiest and more compact way to do it:

```
>>> x = (('a',1), (2,3), (4,), (None,), ())
>>> filter(None, map(lambda i: str(i[0]) if len(i) > 0 and i[0] != None else None, x))
['a', '2', '4']
```

Comment: This solution won't work in case of an empty tuple or a None element. In case of empty tuple, it will be IndexError and in case of a (None, None) tuple, it will be 'None'. However, a compact solution nonetheless in case of filtered tuple of tuple.

Comment: Actually, you can edit your answer to further simplify the solution, like this:   
filter(None, map(lambda i: str(i[0]) if i and i[0] else None, x))

Answer (score 1):

Use `itemgetter`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
f = itemgetter(0)

def func(i):
    if not i:
        return None
    r = f(i)
    if r:
        return str(r)
```

Using it:

```
>>> x = (('a',1), (2,3), (4,), None, '', False, [], (None,), ())
>>> filter(None, map(func, x))
['a', '2', '4']
```

---

You can make it into a function:

```
def extract_first_non_none(collection):
    return filter(None, map(func, collection))
```

Or into a class:

```
class Extractor():
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.getter = itemgetter(index)

    def _func(self, item):
        if not item:
            return None
        r = self.getter(item)
        if r != None:
            return str(r)

    def extract(self, collection):
        return filter(None, map(self._func, collection))
```

Using the class:

```
>>> x = (('a',1), (2,3), (4,), None, '', False, [], (None,), ())
>>> e = Extractor(0)
>>> e.extract(x)
['a', '2', '4']
```

Comment: Pretty new to me. Thanks for the solution. However, it need fix in case of x = ((None,)). I will update the question to include this use case as well.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam My solution works for that. Just try it - edited it in to reflect.

Comment: I updated the question for better understanding. I want the solution to skip the None just like the original code instead of presenting a 'None'. Please edit your answer to include one more condition like if i and f(i).

Comment: @thiruvenkadam I updated my answer, it looks even nicer now :)